# OllyDbg won't jump to command from stack

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I'm using OllyDBG 2.0 on Win7 Ultimate x64. Whenever I debug an .exe, olly refuses to jump to a command when I double click a call in the stack. Olly 1 does this fine. Any way I could fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade to OllyDbg 1.10 - It is not a joke. IMO OllyDbg 1.10 is still the better choice. Version 2 code analyzer is very slow and as a whole it misses some small extras as this.

Comment: even with the recent release sep 27 ?

Comment: @Seki - yes actually, it is still very slow on the analysis. Maybe it is better for some specific tasks, but for plain assembly programming v1.10 is better (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

If you mark and rightclick a stack location, there will be the options to "Follow in Disassembler/Dump/Stack" according to what the target memory might be. If "Follow in Disassembler" is available, the option can also be accessed by pressing Enter while the stack address is selected.